# Why new row can not be added in table with easyui datagrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, jquery-easyui

In my project, I use easyui, and i added toolbar in table.

The head of page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/plugins/jquery.datagrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/plugins/jquery.edatagrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/locale/easyui-lang-zh_CN.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar/lhgcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar/lhgcalendar.js"></script>
```

Some code of page is like:

```
<div class="table" style="height:100%;width:100%;padding-bottom:50px">
<table id="storInfoTB" border=1px cellspacing=0 style="width:100%" class="easyui-datagrid" data-options=""></table>
</div>

<script> 
$("#storInfoTB").datagrid({
 ..........
 toolbar: [{
   id: "con",   
   text: "<input type=\"text\" id=\"content\" placeholder=\"...\"/>",
      },
      {
        id: "search",   
        text: "search somthing",
        iconCls: "icon-search"                  
      },
      {
        id: "add",  
        text: "add new Row",
        iconCls: "icon-add",
        handler: function(){
          alert("test");
          $("#storInfoTB").edatagrid("addRow",0);
        }
      },
      {
        id: "modify",   
        text: "edit selected Row",
        iconCls: "icon-edit"                    
      },
      {
        id: "delete",   
        text: "delete selected Row",
        iconCls: "icon-cut"                 
      },
      {
        id: "back", 
        text: "return",
        iconCls: "icon-undo"                    
       }],
      ......
    });
```

Now i want to add a row in table by clicking the add button. I have tested that it can display test information, but "edatagrid" is fail.

There is should be a new blank row after clicking the add button, but it is not OK.

I need someone's help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out this problem. you must register this function before using edatagrid

```
$(function(){
  $("#storInfoTB").edatagrid({});
});
```